# Trying to get radio button and checkbox to work together in an if statement

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jradiobutton

I don't even know if this code is right, I'm still new to java and have no clue if this is even right. It's meant to be 2 radio buttons and a checkbox when male checkbox is selected and checkbox C1 is selected then it opens a new class but nothing happens

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class WordDocumentTest extends JFrame {


    JCheckBox C1 = new JCheckBox("Safety Switch"); 
    JRadioButton male = new JRadioButton("male");
    JRadioButton female = new JRadioButton("Female");
    private JPanel p1=new JPanel();



    public WordDocumentTest(String s){
        super(s);
        Container content=getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Font f=new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD,20);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    p1.add(C1);
    p1.add(male);
    p1.add(female);


    content.add(p1);

    this.add(male);
    this.add(female);



    JRadioButton button1 = male;
    JRadioButton button2 = female;
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(button1);
    group.add(button2);



    setSize(250,400);    setVisible(true);
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        Object target=e.getSource();

        if (C1.isSelected() && male.isSelected()){
            new MyFrame("");
            }

    }
}
```

Any tips or anything would help a bunch thanks

Comment: You didn't add an listeners to your components. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for working examples that show how to write listeners to interact with your components.

Comment: thanks didn't see that